# Word or phrase for when someone opens their arms wide proposing a hug

Tags: phrase-requests

What's the correct way to refer to the action of one opening their arms wide to offer a hug?

I've been thinking about "hug request", "hug proposal" and "hug offer" but none of these seem quite correct.

Context: I believe I've misunderstood a person's physical expression, thinking it was more of a shrug than a (the word/phrase I'm looking for), and I'd like to apologize for that.

Comment: *Open arms* -- The idiom *open arms* also has a very positive sense of welcoming/ receiving with warmth, kindness, pleasure, happiness, enthusiasm and without reservations, all which an embrace is symbolic of.

Comment: Seems like what you’ve got there is already good enough. But [opinions may vary](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment15959_4732).

Comment: @tchrist Yes, I've already solved this issue a couple hours ago, didn't mark any answer as accepted until now in order to don't discourage other answerers -- that is, keeping this question in the "acive" list for a while longer. I've accepted an answer now.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté - An obscure animated twist would be to incorporate the TV-Trope ["meadowrun"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MeadowRun) - _"I apologize.  I thought your shrug was going to be a meadowrun."_

Comment: @ipso heh, maybe a bit too obscure, but very nice to know about, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Arms wide open" is a common phrase.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But it also has the meaning of "being welcoming" depending on the context, right?

Comment: I guess that's because people usually welcome with a hug!

Comment: Also common with the shrug as OP already noted.

Comment: Heh, makes sense. +1 for your help, I'll leave the question for a bit more of time to give others a chance to answer as well. I'll try to fit it in a phrase meanwhile in a way that it doesn't get ambiguous as @Kris mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe I've misunderstood a person's physical expression, thinking it was more of a shrug than an [invite for a hug](http://www.timeandspacemagazine.com/2009/08/summerworks-say-nothing-saw-wood.html), and I'd like to apologize for that.

Comment: Looks great! Thanks for the help. Too bad I can only mark one answer as accepted.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Não tem problema, fique a vontade. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is my own made up slang but I would call this process *hug-baiting*.  And people would understand.

Comment: "hug-baiting" sounds perfect for casual situations, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**[Brachiation](http://english_contemporary.enacademic.com/23999/brachiation)** is the *process of branching out, process of putting forth arms* but it is associated with locomotion or swinging from tree to tree, and not the action of opening, or to **open arms**: *an eager or warm welcome* (New Collegiate Dictionary. 2001.)

I found one use for the action of "opening their arms wide to offer a hug" under the word 'open' listed as:

> **Spread** ; expanded. He received his son with open arms -An American
> dictionary of the English language; ... . Webster, Noah, 1758-1843.

but I suspect there may be a derivation from the many synonyms for the word 'hug', or the desire to do the action:

**Clip**: To hug or embrace -A classical dictionary of the vulgar tongue. . Grose, Francis, 1731?-1791.

**Halch**: To hug

**Cingulomania**: In a male, a strong desire to hold a girl in one's arms. A term possibly coined by J.E. Schmidt for the Lecher's Lexicon (1967).